# How do I fixe the "Shapely python module not found" error when enabling 'Archipack 2D to 3D'?

Tags: add-on, error, archipack-add-on

May I know how to use Archipack 2D to 3D add-on? Do I have to remove the old version and install the new version 1.3.3? I have disabled the old version and installed the new one and enabled it. After installing the add-on I'm getting this error:

> WARNING Shapely python module not found 2d to 3d tools are disabled
>   see setup in documentation

[Addon available here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?417856-Addon-Archipack)

[image]

What does it mean and do I have to install some add-on or how to get rid of that warning?

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_QPmuff5Vs)

In the document its mention to install some shapely python

[shapely](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely)

How to install that? It's some other extension.

How can I use it as I cant see the tool in the Tools shelf.

Comment: Archipack 1.3.x and shapely setup instructions are in the [archipack wiki](https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/wiki/Setup) Daniel Pool made a great video tutorial for the setup under windows.